# Is this definition closed set axiom wrong

Tags: general-topology

[image]

Here is the capture from website proofwiki: closed set axioms

let $F$ be the subset of the $\mathcal P(S)$,how come the intersection of subset of $F$ can be an element of $F$

If so, I might have some weakness in set theory, please enlighten me.

Answer (score 2):

This is a somewhat confusing, but entirely standard, abuse of language.

If $\mathscr{A}$ is a family of sets, and $S = \{A_i ~|~ i \in I\} \subseteq \mathscr{A}$ is a subset of this family, then we define the intersection of $S$ to be

$$ \bigcap S = \bigcap \{A_i ~|~ i \in I\} = \bigcap_{i \in I} A_i$$

Thus, in your case, if $F$ is a subset of the set of all closed sets, we have $F = \{C_i ~|~ i \in I\}$ a family of closed sets. The intersection of $F$ is exactly the intersection of the sets in $F$, that is, $\bigcap_{i \in I} C_i$, which is exactly what we would expect as an axiom for closed sets -- arbitrary intersections of closed sets are closed.

As an aside, people do the same thing with unions:

$$ \bigcup S = \bigcup \{A_i ~|~ i \in I\} = \bigcup_{i \in I} A_i$$

---

I hope this helps ^_^

Comment: That's truely hepful. I thought the intersection of family of set would be the form of subset of $\mathcal P(S)$, however it defined as the intersection of all the element of family of set, that make sense in definition! Then what if the intersection is not over a single collection of set (e.g your example), but intersection of two family of set, is my way of understanding correct? (e.g will be a form as subset of  $\mathcal P(S)$

Comment: If we have two families $\mathscr{A}$ and $\mathscr{B}$ both subsets of $\mathcal{P}(S), then $\bigcap \mathscr{A}$ is a subset of $S$ while $\mathscr{A} \cap \mathscr{B}$ is a subset of $\mathcal{P}(S)$. Hopefully that clarifies things ^_^

Comment: would you please re-edit the format. Thank you.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't quite understand what you're asking for. Would you like me to add this information to my answer, as opposed to leaving it in the comments?

Comment: It's not an abuse of language at all. Writing $\bigcup_{i \in I} A_i$ is actually more of an abuse than writing $\bigcup \mathcal{A}$, which is more standard (in set theory!).

Comment: @HallaSurvivor I believe the wacky format in your following reply answer due to you missed $$ sign. Check your following reply you will see.

Answer (score 1):

$\mathcal{F} \subseteq \mathscr{P}(S)$ just says that $\mathcal{F}$ is a collection of subsets of $S$, and the first axiom says that if $\mathcal{F}' \subseteq \mathcal{F}$ (so a subcollection of the closed subsets $\mathcal{F}$) then $\bigcap \mathcal{F}' = \{x \in S: \forall A \in \mathcal{F}': x \in A\}$, (which is always a well-defined subset of $S$, so a member of $\mathscr{P}(S)$), is also a member of $\mathcal{F}$, i.e. any intersection of subsets of $S$ that we call "closed" is still "closed". This is just standard set theory notation. Just realise that a subset of the powerset of $S$ is a set of subsets of $S$ (which is often called a "collection" of subsets as well, though a set and a collection and a family etc. are all mathematically the same thing). And if we have a set of subsets of $S$ we can look at their common elements (intersection) as a subset of $S$ or their union as well (open sets are closed under all unions).

Comment: If we have two collections of subset of $S$, is their intersection should be the subset of  $\mathcal P(S)$

Comment: @LawrenceGuo Yes, but that's not what this axiom says. We are talking about a fixed set of subsets $\mathcal{F}$ and a single subcollection of that whose intersection is a subset of $S$ not of $\mathscr{P}(S)$.